# Find Length of smallest substring which contains another string as subsequence

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

Let’s say I have a string `s1 = "eabegcghdefgh"` and another string `s2 = "egh"`.

The code should return answer *4* because of the substring `"efgh"` of `s1` (since it’s the smallest substring which contains `s2` as a subsequence).

> *Note:* There can be a couple of substrings possible, but `"efgh"` is the smallest such substring.

In other words, find the length of smallest substring of `s1` which contains all characters of another string `s2`, but in order.

Please note: I want to ask how to do it in O(n) time complexity.

Comment: nice problem. What did you try so far? O(n) will probably require some sophisticated bookkeeping. I'd investigate something like: throw away all characters that don't (or cannot) play a role and then search all occurrences of the string. If you memorise the original position of the characters, you know the length. It's tricky though.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String smallestWindow(String S, String T) {
    if (S.equals(T))  //If S and T are equal, then simply return S.
        return S;
    /**
     * Use sliding window.
```

If a substring W of S exists such that T is a subsequence of W,
then a substring of S that is longer than or have the same length as W must also exist.
Therefore, find such a substring of S starting from index 0 in S and index 0 in T.
If the last character of T is reached, then the current index in S is the end index of the substring, and find the maximum possible start index of the substring in S.
After the start index and the end index are found, the minimum window size can be updated, and store the start index and the end index as well.

Then set the index in T to 0 and try to find another substring in S.
Repeat the process until the end of S is reached.
After all the characters in S are visited, the minimum substring length can be obtained, and return the shortest substring.

```
     */
    int sLength = S.length(), tLength = T.length();
    int start = 0, end = sLength - 1;
    int sIndex = 0, tIndex = 0;
    while (sIndex < sLength) {
        if (S.charAt(sIndex) == T.charAt(tIndex))
            tIndex++;
        if (tIndex == tLength) {
            int rightIndex = sIndex;
            tIndex--;
            while (tIndex >= 0) {
                if (S.charAt(sIndex) == T.charAt(tIndex))
                    tIndex--;
                sIndex--;
            }
            sIndex++;
            if (rightIndex - sIndex < end - start) {
                start = sIndex;
                end = rightIndex;
            }
            tIndex = 0;
        }
        sIndex++;
    }
    int windowSize = end - start + 1;
        return S.substring(start, start + windowSize);
}
```

Comment: This seems like a good approach to me, but it's not O(n). To see why, suppose that `S` is a string of *p* a's and `T` is a string of *q* a's. Then this approach requires O((p−q)×q) time, because there are O(p−q) calls to the backtracking loop and each one requires O(q) time. So if *p* = 2q, then *n* = 3q and this approach requires O(n²/9) = O(n²) time.

Answer (score -1):

This is a basic Sliding window problem often known as "Smallest window in a string containing all the characters of another string ". We approach this problem by having two pointers "low" and "high" starting at the first index of the string to be searched and we increment the high pointer until all the characters of the pattern is matched and then we try to shrink the substring by incrementing the low pointer.

Here is a java snippet for the problem.

```
 public static String smallestWindow(String s, String pat){
    if(s == null || s.length() == 0)return "-1";
    int map[] = new int[128];
for(char k : pat.toCharArray())
map[k]++;
int count =0,start=-1,end=-1,lo=0,hi=0,min= Integer.MAX_VALUE;

for(hi = 0;hi<s.length();hi++)
{
    if(map[s.charAt(hi)] >0)
     count++;

     map[s.charAt(hi)]--;

     if(count == pat.length())
     {
         while(lo<hi && map[s.charAt(lo)] <0)
         { map[s.charAt(lo)]++;
             lo++;
         }
         if(min > hi - lo +1)
         {
             min = hi - lo+1;
             start = lo;
             end = hi+1;
         }
         map[s.charAt(lo)]++;

         lo++;
         count--; 
     }
}
return start == -1? "-1" : s.substring(start,end);
}
```

i recommend you to watch this video to understand it well. [Smallest window in a string containing all the characters of another string](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eS6PZLjoaq8)

Comment: The questions aren't the same, a string containing all the characters of another string does not imply that the other string is a subsequence of the first.